# How to permanently commit and push git hook file?

Tags: git

i want to have a post-checkout in .../.git/hooks permanently, so when others do a clone, they can get it as well.

How should i do that please ? guess this has to happen in the git server side ? Many thanks !

Comment: What do you want the git hook to do? Based on that it depends whether it is client side or server side?

Comment: i want to copy 1 file from other repo, each time i clone this repo

Comment: Thats not a good use case for a git-hook. Is it being copied locally? If so what if the person does not have the other repo? I would rather add the file in your repository.

Comment: it's copied from remote repo, don't ask my why, but this is the best way for our situation now, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and I'll tell you why: clone my repository that installs a post-checkout hook that immediately removes your entire home directory.

Allowing `git clone` to execute arbitrary actions based on what was downloaded is a gaping security hole, and that's why Git does not do it.  Or rather, why Git does not do it *now*—it was, by mistake, possible in the past on systems that did case-folding during file system lookup.  But it *must not* be allowed.

What you can do is include in your repository a program that, when *voluntarily* run by whoever clones the repository, installs a hook—and then give your users instructions that they should run this program themselves.  You cannot force them to do it; you can only make it easy for them.  But they must do this of their own volition, perhaps *after* inspecting your code to make sure it is safe.

Comment: i get your point, this is my plan, let the git server admin add a service side hook, which calls $project_dir/my_init.sh, just this 1 line.  Now in our repo, we have the full control of what this my_init.sh is, we won't allow anything funny goes into it. How's this ?

Comment: It doesn't really help: you control your server, but why should I, or anyone who is not you, trust you and your server? Maybe whoever broke into Equifax broke into your server. :-) I must first clone (safely), then inspect, and only after inspecting, I can install your `.sh` file into my `.git/hooks/` directory, or run your `.sh` file that installs something into my `.git/hooks/` directory.

Comment: well, if someone can always break into the server, then nothing is safe anyway. My assumption is, i choose to trust our IT department, assume the git server behind the firewall is safe. I'm talking about the intranet here.

Comment: Git is designed for people who don't have reason to trust everyone else.

Comment: understood, in our case, this is for the work, the scope is intranet. Actually what i need is a simple link from 1 repo to the other, but seems subtree/submodule way too complicated.

Comment: Then, instead of having people run `git clone`, have them run your script that runs `git clone` and installs a hook. The hook itself can come from the repository just cloned, or can be part of the script they are to run that will do the `git clone`. That way people just run one command; it's just not `git clone`.

Comment: that could work, if the team agrees, i've been trying to avoid this way, but ... thx !